# Input the output of one program into another program

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a billing software for which I need to take the output of one cpp program as an input in the second program.
eg:
In program 1, the user chose multiple things which made the to the value 'bill'=100.
I need Program 2 to read the value of 'bill' which was 100 in the end of program 1, and then add/subtract whatever the user does to this (interger?) and print the final value in the end of program #2..
I don't know if i explained it correctly but you can take a rough idea of what I meant..

Comment: Maybe you want to explore using inter-process communication mechanisms like pipes, etc.

Comment: Or, a database?

Comment: There are a range of possibilities. You can write the result out to file, or print the result and use pipes to pass it on to the next program, etc... Do you have a more specific idea of how you want to use these programs?

Comment: So the first program should write the result to some file and the second program should read that file. This is the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there are many alternatives. However, I do not suggest the solutions like writing out to a file and reading from another program because you can face with problems like synchronization issues while accessing the file or bottleneck issues (may not be issue in this case but it may happen during big data transfers) regarding file I/O performance. Using mechanisms such as pipes or sockets would be a better solution.

If your software is using Qt Framework, I recommend using Qt Remote Objects. Both PyQt and Qt with C++ support QtRO communication.

In QtRO, the objects can be shared between applications through a defined interface. The source node (program 1) shares the object that contains bill. The clients can access the replicas of the shared object and get properties. When the replica is received, it can be used like any other QObject.

For more information about Qt Remote Objects check out: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtremoteobjects-index.html